# Yii2 Functional test send ajax get request not working

Tags: yii2, codeception

I am trying to test an ajax request with a basic install of Yii2. I am just using the SiteController::actionAbout() method to try this out.

```
public function actionAbout()
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

    return [
        'message' => 'hello world',
        'code' => 100,
    ];
}
```

And in the test:

```
public function sendAjax(\FunctionalTester $I)
{
    $I->sendAjaxGetRequest('site/about');
    $r = $I->grabResponse();

    die(var_dump($r));
}
```

The grab response method is one I wrote myself in a \Helper\Functional.php file:

```
public function grabResponse()
{
    return $this->getModule('Yii2')->_getResponseContent();
}
```

When I dump out the response, I just see the html from the site/index page. 
This happens for any route except the site default. If I try to do the same thing using site/index then it returns:

```
string(36) "{"message":"hello world","code":100}"
```

What am I missing / doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the difference between a [Yii route](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing) and the actual URL.

The argument to [sendAjaxGetRequest()](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser#sendAjaxGetRequest) is the URL, not the route (at least if you pass it as a string, see below).

Dependent on your UrlManager config you might have URLs like `/index.php?r=site/about`, where the route is `site/about`. You can use the Url helper of Yii to create the URL:

```
$I->sendAjaxGetRequest(\yii\helpers\Url::to(['site/about']));
```

I am not sure about this but if you have the Codeception Yii2 module installed you should also be able to pass the route like this:

```
$I->sendAjaxGetRequest(['site/about']);
```